# SDL issues on playing sound when switch audio device

Tags: c++, audio, sdl, multimedia

I got an issue with SDL, after I successfully init SDL audio and run SDL_OpenAudio() , everything goes well ,but if disconnect the current audio device or switch to another , SDL_AudioCallBack() never runs again and SDL_CloseAudio()\SDL_QuitSubSystems() can not return . 
 so, how can I fix this ? thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can learn [ask] and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score -1):

solved out, cuz SDL uses XAudio2 defaultly, but this goes unsuitable in SDL,maybe a issue on SDL or XAudio2.
 then I use DirectSound as the driver , code runs fine.

SetEnvironmentVariable(L"SDL_AUDIODRIVER",L"directsound"); // tell SDL use DirectSound